# How to append extra text to ListView via SimpleCursorAdapter?

Tags: android, sql, listview, simplecursoradapter

I've this piece of code:

```
String[] columns = new String[] { 
    MySQLiteHelper.COL_EXAMS_DESC,
    MySQLiteHelper.COL_EXAMS_MRK_TEMP,
    MySQLiteHelper.COL_EXAMS_MRK,
    MySQLiteHelper.COL_EXAMS_CFU};

int[] to = new int[] { 
    R.id.exam_description, 
    R.id.exam_subtitle,
    R.id.exam_mark, 
    R.id.exam_cfu};

dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
    R.layout.single_exam_info, cursor, columns, to, 0);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_exams);
listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Now, `MySQLiteHelper.COL_EXAMS_MRK_TEMP` is a particular field which sometimes is empty, sometimes isn't. When it's displayed (so when it's not empty), I would like to append some sort of label to it. How can I do it?

`CursorWrapper` doesn't look good in this case: I don't have to filter results, I simply have to sometimes add a String to one of the results, sometimes I don't.
Adding an *ad-hoc* `TextView` isn't ok too: how do I know when to populate it?

I wondering if there's and option to manually build the ListView, iterating the cursor and in every cycle checking if the filed is empty or not...

Comment: You're going to have to switch to an ArrayListAdapter, sorry bud. I ran into this myself, and I looked and looked and looked until I gave up and went with hashmaps and an arraylist. I don't have the code with me right now, I'll post an answer this evening with more details.
But it will do exactly what you want, that much I can guarantee

Comment: Oh Gosh, I hoped I could avoid it. Never mind. I'll wait the code, thanks man!

Comment: GAH! Sorry, forgot about it by the time I got home. I'll be sure to take a look and lay it out nice and easy for you. The jist of it is you loop through the rows of the cursor adding them to the hashmap, then you can just concatenate onto the end of them as need be

Answer (score 0):

I ended up extending the SimpleCursorAdapter, overriding newView() and bindView(). That's the only, and easiest, way to do it.

Comment: Oh! Well I guess if you've already solved it.... I'll come back alter and toss an "answer" in though, just in case :)